# How do I open incoming connections in Ubuntu under VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, port-forwarding

An Ubuntu application in VirtualBox under OS X says incoming TCP connections are not working.

My VirtualBox network settings (NAT).

```
Host IP: 127.0.0.1
Host Port: PPPP (>=1024)
Guest IP: 10.0.2.15
Guest Port: PPPP
```

My AirPort Express settings:

```
Public TCP Port: PPPP
Private IP Address: 10.0.1.3
Private TCP Ports: PPPP
```

How can I let the incoming connections through? Let me know any tests to pinpoint the problem.

EDIT: The host IP is 10.0.1.3 on my local network, but I guess this is synonymous with 127.0.0.1 (localhost) since VirtualBox is running on that very host. Unless this is the error?

Comment: You’re (effectively) listening at `127.0.0.1`. Is that intentional?

Comment: See my edit regarding the host IP.

Comment: If you want anyone to be able to connect your Ubuntu system from your local network then a bridge should be used instead of a NAT for your Ubuntu system to have a reachable IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listening at `127.0.0.1` means to *not* listen “on the network”. It is *not* the same as using no IP (in VirtualBox) or `0.0.0.0` (in general), which means to listen on all interfaces.

It is of course also not the same as using `10.0.1.3` or whatever specific interface you want a program (or port forwarding) to listen on.

`127.0.0.1` or `localhost` can only be reached on the same machine. That’s because every network device is their own `localhost`.

**tl;dr**: Remove `127.0.0.1`, the end.